# Rails 2.3.8: Validating an object before save shows previous references and not updated ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

There's a form on my site allowing to update an object (i.e. Book).
The book contains the field author_id which references the Author class.
The form allows changing the author.

When saving the book, validations are run,
but when a certain validation calls self.author, it will receive the previous author and not the new one that was chosen.
To deal with this problem, I always have to start the validations with reloading the new author in the following way:

```
def some_validation
    author = Author.find(self.author_id)
    ...
 end
```

Why won't the validation see the new author, and how can I make it see it,
without having to reload the new referenced object every time?

Thanks!

Comment: please post code from your `update` action

Comment: The update is just a plain obj.save, which in turn calls the validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem you can duplicate in the console:

```
b = Book.new
=> #<Book id:nil, etc...>
b.author_id = 1
=> 1
b.author
=> #<Author id:1, etc...>
b.author_id = 2
=> 2
b.author
=> #<Author id:1, etc...>
```

so... changing the association ID (which is what the form update_attributes does) doesn't change the loaded associated object.

but, if you nullify the object first, the associated object does reload:

```
b.author = nil
=> nil
b.author_id = 2
=> 2
b.author
=> #<Author id:2, etc...>
```

So you *can* (note the italics, because I don't *know* what is the best solution) set the object to nil in the controller if the association id is in the params hash, or continue using your method, but add a guard to only reload if necessary

```
author = Author.find(self.author_id) if self.author_id_changed?
```

(sorry if that was a lot of rambling that essentially didn't answer your question ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there is a solution more inherent to the framework, without needing me to nullify fields or reload them manually..

Comment: The Rails rule I like is that if it's difficult, you're probably doing it wrong: could it be that the validations you're trying to do in the Book model would be better done in the Author model, and then you can use validates_associated....